# How to get the value of gameobject array from one script to another?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm new in c# and arcore. I have an example controller script called GUIController.cs and another list of item call ItemScrollList.cs. I made a gameobject with arrays in GUIController with 2 prefabs element 0 and 1.. What I'm trying to achieve is, Everytime I click on the content of itemscrollList (in this case 2 items that is item1 and item2) I need to change the prefab on GUIController.

The errors I got from the codes below is everytime I click on content item 1 or 2 they return nullpointerexceptions.

The line on GUIController.cs "AndyPrefab = nowPrefabs.GetComponent().currentPrefabs;" is the line I need it to show the prefab properly. Please help me

GUIController.cs

```
if (hit.Trackable is FeaturePoint)
                     {
                         AndyPrefab = AndyPlanePrefab[0];
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //this is manual input value AndyPlanePrefab as array 1
                         //AndyPrefab = AndyPlanePrefab[1]; 

                         //this is where i need it to properly show the correct prefab
                         AndyPrefab = nowPrefabs.GetComponent<ItemScrollList>().currentPrefabs;
                     }
```

ItemScrollList.cs

```
//this is where i create the button for itemlist
private void AddButtons()
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < itemList.Count; i++)
      {
          Item item = itemList[i];
          GameObject newButton = buttonObjectPool.GetObject();
          newButton.transform.SetParent(contentPanel);
          ItemButton itemButton = newButton.GetComponent();
          itemButton.Setup(item, this);
      }
  }

//this is where im trying to change the prefabs and connect it to 
GUIController, if i click on item 1 it should change the gameobject[] value 
to AndyPrefab.
  public void TryToChangePrefabs(Item item)
  {
      if (item == itemList[0]) {
          currentPrefabs = changePrefabs.GetComponent().AndyPlanePrefab[0];
          Debug.Log("Condition number 1 done");
      }
      else if (item == itemList[1])
      {
          currentPrefabs = changePrefabs.GetComponent().AndyPlanePrefab[1];
          Debug.Log("Condition number 2 done");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a gameobject variable in the script you want to access the other script from and drag and drop the gameobject with the script you want to access into the gameobject variable to access it you must do this

```
mygameobjectvariable.getComponent<myscriptname>().myarray[1]
```

Comment: since i keep getting null for whatever reason, i change the condition using just static int, but thanks anyway